# Izhikevich Neuron model - equations

Tags: matlab

In literature, papers and a book (e.g., [1] and [2]), I found different equations for the Izhikevich Neuron model.

In [1], I found this:

```
v' = 0.04v^2 + 5v + 140 - u + I
u' = a(bv - u)
if v >= 30 mV => v = c; u = u + d
```

In [2], I found this:

```
C*v' = k(v - v_r)(v - v_t) - u + I_in
  u' = a{b(v - v_r) - u}
if v >= v_peak => v = c; u = u + d
```

I tried to go from the second set of equations to the first set of equations, ignoring the C. I found this:

```
k = 0.04; v_r = -82.6556; v_t = -42.3444
```

However, this gave me complete garbage. Thus, my question is as follows:

Why are there 2 different sets of equations, and which one should I take if I want to simulate Izhikevich neurons?

Bonus question #1: How do I go from set 2 to set 1?

Bonus question #2: Am I correct to state that 'I' is in [pA]?

References:

[1] Simple Model of Spiking Neurons - E.M. Izhikevich (2003)

[2] Dynamical Systems in neuroscience - E.M. Izhikevich (2007)

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about understanding scientific papers, not programming

Comment: People who are undervoting this question obviously are not aware of the Izhikevich spiking neuron model and do not understand the programming issues related to such model.

Comment: It might not be fully related to programming, but I kindly disagree that it has nothing to do with programming. Apologies if I offended someone. I'm happy to have received 1 answer, and 1 useful comment!

Comment: I've asked the same question somewhere else, because I agree that this questions could be asked somewhere else, where it's more suited. So this question can be closed or deleted or whatever. My apologies for asking this question here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) question #1: go from set 2 to set 1:

1.1) create a new variable V:

```
V = C(v - v_r)
```

1.2) you obtain:

```
(v - v_r) = V / C
v = (V / C) + v_r
v' = (V' / C) + A
```

1.3) replace (1.2) in set 2 and you'll obtain set 1 with new coefficients:

```
K = k/(C^2) = 0.04
D = (k/C)(v_r - v_t) = 5
E = -CA = 140
B = b/C

V' = KV^2 + DV + E -u +I 
u' = a(BV' - u)
```

2) question #2: is 'I' expressed as [pA]?

yes, it is. v is [mV] and each time step is 1ms

Comment: Muttley, firstly, thank you for answering my question:) If you don't mind, I'd like to ask you a bit more:
- What's the point of having 2 sets of equations, and which makes more sense to use?
- How did you come up with the new variable V?
- In the last equation, shouldn't it be: u' = a(BV - u) instead of V'?

Comment: - Where does the "+ A" come from in the last line of (1.2)?